# Problem with resizing images in batch via PHP

Tags: php, image, resize

I am resizing images in a batch via PHP. When I resize images separately then there is no problem. But when I run in as a batch then all JPGs from 40 image are incorrectly resized.

In batch I resize JPGs and PNGs. PNG are all ok. But from 40 JPG they are not good. 
Example of image which is resized: [source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js8Dr.jpg)

Bad resized image looks like: [bad resized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O19Tl.jpg)

Good resized image (is in first 40 JPGs): [Good resized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPGqz.jpg)

When I update a script to resize only that one image which was bad resized, then all is ok. But it not works in batch. Where can be a problem?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I got it! It was a bug in my code. It was because I setted output quality for PNGs as $quality /= 10;
And all PNGs after that has this poor quality.

Comment: *"It was a bug in my code."* - What code? @Nina asked for code at around the same time the question was asked but there was no update made to the question. You know what went wrong, nobody else. The answer doesn't really work with the question, this is more of a localized issue and won't help anyone else but yourself here P. Danek.

Answer (score -1):

I got it! It was a bug in my code. It was because I setted output quality for PNGs as $quality /= 10; And all PNGs after that has this poor quality.